# Bad pointer error in class when passing array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I'm writing a simple battlesystem for a game and I'm getting an error passing an array of pointers to the battlesystem class.

```
//Create the player and 3 enemies
Battler player("Player", 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 90);
Battler foe1("Imp", 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 80);
Battler foe2("Ogre", 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 75);
Battler foe3("Giant", 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60);

//Create an array of pointers that point to the enemies
Battler *foes[3];
foes[0] = &foe1;
foes[1] = &foe2;
foes[2] = &foe3;

//Initialize the battlesystem passing the player, the array of enemies 
//and the number of enemies (3)
BattleSystem *btl = new BattleSystem(&player, *foes, 3);
```

So this was working fine, but when I pass the array to the class, the first member is passed fine, but the rest are passed and when I do a breakpoint, they are sent as "Badptr".

Here is the code for the battlesystem constructor:

```
BattleSystem::BattleSystem(Battler *plyr, Battler enemies[], int numEnemies)
{
    player = plyr;

    //foe is declared as    Battler *foe;   So it just points to the first member of the enemies
    // array so I can access them. But only the first member gets a value the rest get
    // "Bad ptr" with garbage values and when I look through the enemies array passed
    // to the constructor, it has BAD PTRs in everything but the first element.
    foe = enemies;
    numFoes = numEnemies;

    totalTurns = 0;

    foeTurns = new int[numFoes];
    turnList = new Battler*[numFoes + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i <= numFoes; i++)
    {
        turnList[i] = &foe[i];
    }

    turnList[numFoes + 1] = player1;
```

}

I'm missing something obvious I think, but can anyone share some wisdom?

Thank you.

Comment: Life is so much easier with the standard containers such as `std::vector` and `std::array`, try changing your code to use those if you can. Also can you include the class member variable declarations in your question.

Comment: `BattleSystem *btl = new BattleSystem(&player, *foes, 3);` <- You are *dereferencing* `foes`, which does not make any sense.

Comment: Are you making sure that player will not go out of scope?

Comment: I would have went with the standard containers, but this code is ultimately going to end up crunched down into C for a device that containers are too costly on.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside style issues about naked pointers and ownership, I believe you mean

```
//                                                v-- array of pointers
BattleSystem::BattleSystem(Battler *plyr, Battler *enemies[], int numEnemies)
```

And

```
BattleSystem *btl = new BattleSystem(&player, foes, 3);
```